# MySQL Delete all selected rows in one request

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to `SELECT` specific rows and `DELETE` the selected result in **ONE** request?

```
$res = $Connection->query("SELECT * FROM tasks");
if($res->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){ ...
```

The problem is that I have limited Number of queries to my SQL database and I want to minimize it as mush as possible.

Comment: um you cant select things not there (as you just deleted them)

Comment: i want to do this at once. first select then delete if you prefer..

Comment: ok well do that then

Comment: Whatever you used in your where statement of your select query, just use in your delete query. Also, if you fetch a list of ID's, you can simply do a WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, etc..)

Comment: NO one query can not be a select and a delete. your reason of having limited requests makes no sense - can you explain that?

Comment: That's what i wanted to know then.

Comment: call a stored proc. Is that one request?

Comment: @Dragon Many hostings have limitations on amount of database requests.

Comment: Consider to switch your hoster is the best choice imho.

Comment: sure, yet i have never hit that limit, if you have, then you need to choose the appropriate hosting for the site. as you can get a vps for under $10\month, there's no excuses anymore

Comment: @dognose Maybe later. This one is very cheap, and i want to use it as long as i can.
I was more curious if this was possible, i can live without it but i was sure that was possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using the regular mysql-api in PHP. Just execute two queries. The second one will be so fast that it won't matter. This is a typical example of micro optimization. Don't worry about it. (So timing doesn't matter much)

For the record, since you are worried about the number of queries, it can be done using mysqli and the [mysqli_multi_query-function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

P.S. - **I haven't tried this**, but since this `mysql_multi_query` is there in the documentation, it might help... :)

Answer (score 1):

Both SELECT and DELETE need one request individually. And there is no SQL can do this work in the official documents.